# Joomla php within sourcerer not displayed

Tags: php, plugins, joomla3.0

I have successfully installed sourcerer, but the following code in a module doesnt show the expected result (only TEST1 and TESt2 get displayed). What am I missing?

```
<p>TEST1 
{source} 
<!--?php echo "My first php snippet";
?--> 
{/source} 
TEST2
</p>
```

Comment: The <!-- is added automatically by the editor. This looks strange...

Comment: https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer#code-is-stripped-when-i-save-the-article  This article seems to suggest that there are security levels which ban certain types of script like php if set to do so. Maybe the double brackets syntax is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the article mentioned here is right you need to change

```
 <?php echo "My first php snippet";?>
```

to

```
 [[?php echo "My first php snippet";?]]
```

to avoid it being produced as a comment in html

https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer#code-is-stripped-when-i-save-the-article

Maybe the double brackets syntax mentioned in the article is what you need.

If you are just starting out this little "manual" looks handy
https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer#php-is-not-working

It also appears that there are options you need to set to allow php among other types of script such as javascript or css:
https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/disable-html-filters
 and https://www.gavick.com/documentation/joomla/templates/customization/custom-javascript-css-php-code